# EC2 instance ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, woocommerce

I have a wordpress/woocommerce hosted on AWS. After the volume associated with the instace got 100% full the website stopped working and showing in browser ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.
Last thing i did was to add a massive import of products in woocommerce using WP All Import (Wordpress plugin).
Any ideas why ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT?

I extended the volume, now is at ~60% (from 20 to 30 GB) but the problem persists.

In SSH Apache is running and no security nor firewall was modified.
What could be the issue?

Thanks!

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        29G   20G  9.7G  67% /
tmpfs           987M     0  987M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           395M  844K  394M   1% /run
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/xvda15     105M  5.3M  100M   5% /boot/efi
tmpfs           198M  4.0K  198M   1% /run/user/0
```

[image]

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      813/perl            
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      412/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      752/sshd: /usr/sbin 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585/mysqld          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:33060         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      585/mysqld          
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      547/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      752/sshd: /usr/sbin
```

Comment: Have you also extended the partition or just changed the volume size? Also , check your instance' load , cpu usage and RAM if nothing else has been changed. You can share the output of `df -h` and `htop/top`.

Comment: I edited the question with this info. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: can you show result of `netstat -ntlp`.

Comment: Your issue seems to be with the changes you made. The issue seems to be with wp plugin as the error is 502(can check with inspect in your browser) whiel 302 moved..(x-redirected-by:wordpress) and not with firewall etc. You need to check logs for wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Some simple checks that should be done at this point:

1. Restart relevant services e.g. - run the same for relevant `mysqld` or `php-fpm` services where relevant. These services may have also been affected.

```
     sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
     sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

2. Check your relevant Wordpress debug logs or Apache logs for error messages

```
    less +G /var/log/apache2/error.log
    cat ./wp-content/debug.log   # (if this is enabled in wp-config.php)
```

3. Given your instance isn't part of an auto scaling group or you have health checks temporarily paused, run a reboot of your instance to attempt to bring services back up overall.

There are a number of possible causes you could be seeing this message - the above requests are for some of the minimum details that will be needed to determine the source of the issue and would strongly recommend including these (exempting any sensitive data) for further troubleshooting.